# Github Dependabot Alerts - Babel vulnerable to arbitrary code execution when compiling specifically crafted malicious code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I am getting this alert as ***Critical*** in my Github Repository, Security section for both my Frontend and backend code.

I'm unable to understand what it is. Please explain flaw?

I upgraded my dependencies and this flaw got solved. However, I want to understand what it means and how critical is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is related to a security vulnerability in the Babel compiler.

The vulnerability is identified as **CVE-2023-45133** and has a critical severity rating. The vulnerability can be exploited by an attacker to execute arbitrary code during compilation when using plugins that rely on the `path.evaluate()` or `path.evaluateTruthy()` internal Babel methods. The vulnerability affects versions of `@babel/traverse` prior to 7.23.2 and 8.0.0-alpha.4, as well as all versions of `babel-traverse`.

If you wanna more detail, you can read here:

https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-45133